# How can i fetch only updated events from google calendar php API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to fetch only updated events from google calendar.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "incremental synchronization" functionality in the Calendar API, see:  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

After the initial request:

> Incremental sync is performed repeatedly and updates the client with
>   all the changes that happened ever since the previous sync. Each time,
>   the client provides the previous sync token it obtained from the
>   server and stores the new sync token from the response.

See the `syncToken` argument for the `events.list()` method:  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

The PHP documentation for the relevant methods (to get and set the sync token) is here:  https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Events.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply its very helpfull. Can you provide gcal php api library which supports this functionality.?